# Detect screenshot images for artifacts, lossy compression, or blurriness without original image

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, image-processing, npm

I have a large library of software screenshots of varying quality. Some are high-quality, some are poor since they're a mix of:

- screen grabs of youtube videos
- heavily lossy compressed
- significantly sized down from their native resolution

Often this can result in artifacts, or loss of sharpness.

I'd like to build some sort of score "quality" or perhaps a flag for lossy compression detection. I need to to do this without access to the original image. I've dug around for some npm libraries that can handle this, but no luck. Just found some interesting [metadata](http://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/api-input/#metadata) I can pull.

I also found APIs like [sightengine](https://sightengine.com/image-quality-main-colors) that give me a "blurriness" score. However every screenshot I throw at it, I receive a very sharp score. Seems this API is more for detecting blurry photography/bokeh.

**Is this even possible?** Can anybody point me in the right direction? Manually inspecting pixels/compositions myself is probably going to be a bit over my head.

Comment: I'd start by defining a list of specific and calculable qualities that you can objectively say are present or missing in an image, or have an objective numeric scale (even if you don't yet know how to calculate them yourself). From there, it should be easier to reason about where to go next.

Comment: Not sure if these are calculable, but I don't think I have the domain knowledge to get more specific: 1. presence of artifacts 2. lossy compression detection (maybe the same as #1), 3. blurriness (of lines/text)

Comment: What are "artifacts"? What quantifies a particular group of pixels as an artifact? Compression is certainly quantifiable and I'm guessing that's what you want to use the metadata for. "blurriness" also needs to be defined with an objective unit. When someone generally says that an image is blurry, that's a subjective observation, without a quantifiable scale.